# Update database sortorder column based on array value list

Tags: mysql, database, sorting

I need to update the sort order column based on the sequence of primary key values I get as array list from ajax call. For example I have 2 coulmns (ID, Sortorder) with values (23,1)(32,2)(21,3)(43,4), now the user from the frontend moves the 3rd row(21,3) above second row(32,2) and I get the ID array sequence as 23, 21, 32, 43 which I have to maintain. From this list, I am trying to update the sororder as per the sequence, so the database table values should look as (23,1)(32,**3**)(21,**2**)(43,4). Could you help me to get this DB update statement.

Attached the print screen for better understanding:

[image: Screenshot]

Java logic I have, trying to find an update sql statement to loop from an array list. I have ~1000 rows in my table and with my logic, this would trigger 1000 update queries, I don't think this is efficient. Trying to find an alternate efficient way.

```
Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    conn = getConnection();
    String query = "update Sortordertable set sortorder = ? where Id = ? ";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement

    String str[]=String.valueOf(s.getRecordId()).split(";");//id1;id;id3;.... list I get from ajax call
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        pstmt.setId(1,i++);  //set sortorder value as 1, 2, 3..
        pstmt.setInt(2, str[i]); // In this line I want to use my array-list to update my table.
        pstmt.executeUpdate(); // execute update statement
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried and explain why it did not work?

Comment: Hi Richard, Updated my java logic in my question. I have ~1000 rows in my table and with my logic, this would trigger 1000 update queries, I don't think this is efficient. Trying to find an alternate efficient way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific use case you have showed, you could use the following query, which would update only the rows with `id=32` or `id=23`.

```
UPDATE t1 SET 
  sortorder = CASE WHEN id = 32 THEN 3 ELSE 2 END
WHERE id IN   (32, 21);
```

This could be adapted for multiple updates if you don't update the database after each operation. but will grow with the number of operations made by the user before the update is triggered.

**Edit to address comment:**

If, as in the example given in your comment, you want to move the row with order 4 to the first row, you can use the following:

```
UPDATE t1 SET 
  sortorder = CASE WHEN sortorder = 4 THEN 1 ELSE sortorder + 1 END
WHERE sortorder <= 4;
```

I've added a where clause in that last query to illustrate that you can easily adapt this to different use case.

Comment: Thanks Richard for you response. Your solution works good if we do the swap, but we have to re update all the sortorder row values. For example, if we move 4rt row (43,4) to the first position(on first table), then it has to change all the sortorder values as (23,2) (32,3) (21,4) &(43,1).

Comment: Richard, Thanks for the update. Just to further understand, does the above update refresh all the sortorder column values once we move the position. How about if we move 4th row to second position? Table values should be like (23,1)(32,3)(21,4)(43,2).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_update_positions`(
    IN `p_positions` VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN

    SET @positions = REPLACE(p_positions, ',', '),(');
    SET @positions = CONCAT('(', @positions, ')');

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmpPositions;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpPositions(
        `position` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        `order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
    );

    SET @insertString = CONCAT('INSERT INTO tmpPositions (`order_id`) VALUES ', @positions);

    PREPARE insertStatement FROM @insertString;
    EXECUTE insertStatement;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE insertStatement;

    UPDATE orders
    INNER JOIN tmpPositions ON order_id = orders.id
    SET orders.Sortorder = tmpPositions.position;

    SELECT ROW_COUNT() AS rowCount;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you call it like this:

```
CALL sp_update_positions('24,23,21,22');
```